# Problems with Primefaces confirm dialog with update attribute

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am currently working on implementing primefaces confirm dialog in my application.  This is my code which is giving the error related to update attribute and the confirm dialog is not functioning as expected.

```
 <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Delete" ajax="true" action="# 
  {customerBean.deleteCustomer}" update="deptsec" immediate="true" 
  styleClass="submit-button" style="display: inline-b 
   lock;margin-right: 40px;" 
                                                                                  onsuccess="PF('editCustPop').hide()">
                                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" 
  message="Are you sure, You want to delete?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                                    </p:commandButton>

  <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" 
  type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                                        <p:commandButton value="No" 
  type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
 </p:confirmDialog>
```

and also, i am not able to see that ui-icon-check and ui-icon-close icons. could you let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: You say that you code is `giving the error related to update attribute` and `not functioning as expected.` What error are you getting? And what behaviour is expected? You may want to consult [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the help.

Comment: @rh16: you can type [ mvcve ] without the spaces to automatically get [mcve].